# sql server pivot into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

### How can I pivot this

```
ID         Allocate
552779  A - Level 2 Tier 1
552779  G - Level 2 Tier 2
552779  O -  4 Units
```

Into this

> ```
>                1           2            3
> ```
>
> 552779   |  A - Level 2 Tier 1  |    G - Level 2 Tier 2   |   O -  4 Units

- Bearing in mind that Allocate can be any string value from a set of 86 possible known strings? Do I need to use another technique other than Pivot to do this - there can be a mximum of 6 strings on the new record as this will be the maximum amount of times that the ID will be associated with the different strings
- this has to be dynamic in nature with 6 possible columns but there may be ID numbers that have only one string associated with it plus 5 nulls and another ID that has the maximum six strings associated with it and various other combinations within 1 - 6.

Comment: Where is the code that you already have?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH OrderedItems AS (
    SELECT ID
          ,Allocate
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Allocate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Table
)
SELECT Id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Allocate ELSE NULL END) AS [1]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN Allocate ELSE NULL END) AS [2]
       ...
FROM OrderedItems
GROUP BY Id
```

You can use pivot for the last part if you want

Comment: I should have said there are thousands of id's repeated in column 1 with various strings in the allocate field so the rowcount will be large?

Comment: @user1491269, oops, forgot to partition the row numbers. Fixed